# How to convert a magento website into a mobile responsive website on a subdomain?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to develop a magento extension which copies the existing website on https://m.mywebsite.com with a mobile responsive theme and custom javascript. How can i automate the process of copying the website and enabling the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that [you create a website](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html) throught the configuration and set the domain you want along with the theme you need for mobile. Another option is to set a specific theme and to [set exceptions on the design configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5752/9489).